# Update nth item in array in state in parent from child in React?

Tags: reactjs

In my top level component I have a function to update state. I pass this down to different child elements so that they can update my main state.

In my top level component:

```
  updateValue(item, value) {
    this.setState({[item]: parseInt(value)});
  }
```

This has worked so far however now I need to update the nth item in an array.

My top level state is like this:

```
this.state = {
  chosenExercises: [
    'Bench press',
    'Squat',
    'Pull up'
  ]
};
```

And in my child component Im trying to do something like:

```
this.props.updateValue('chosenExercises'[1], 'New exercise');
```

So that my state would then be:

```
this.state = {
  chosenExercises: [
    'Bench press',
    'New exercise',
    'Pull up'
  ]
};
```

Am I going about this the correct way? Or should my state be key value pairs?

```
this.state = {
  chosenExercises: {
    0: 'Bench press',
    1: 'New exercise',
    2: 'Pull up'
  }
};
```

This would potentially solve some of my problems of making the exercises easier to target but Im not sure which is best practice.

Comment: Your state is an object.  So you can keep data inside the state at any format you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the chosenExercises can be multiple it makes sense to make it as an array, however you need to update your state differently. Instead of passing the index of the array element to update, you should actually make a copy of the array, update it in the child element and then send the updated array to the parent.

You could do something like:

In Child:

```
updateValue = (item, index, value) => {
   let newValue = [...this.props[item].slice(0, index), value, ...this.props[item].slice(index + 1)];
   this.props.updateValue(item, newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with this is that your state has to remain immutable so you have to provide a new Array to update in your state. So you'll end up with something like:

```
this.updateValue('chosenExercises', 1, 'New exercise');


updateValue(item, index, value) {
  const newArray = this.state[item].slice();
  newArray[index] = value;
  this.setState({ [item]: newArray });
}
```

The `array.slice()` function creates a new Array, in which you update the value by its index. Afterwards you update your component state with the new array.

---

If you happen to do this more often, React created an immutability helper for these things. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html). This would let you do something like:

```
import update from 'react-addons-update';

this.setState({
  [item]: update(this.state[item], {[index]: {$set: value } })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with this in the top level component:

```
  updateValue(item, value, options) {
    if (options.isChosenExercises === true) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let newchosenExercises = prevState.chosenExercises.slice();
        newchosenExercises[item] = value;
        return {chosenExercises: newchosenExercises};
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({[item]: parseInt(value)});
    }
  }
```

For normal uses pass an empty object as the last parameter:

```
this.props.updateValue('setLength', e.target.value, {})}
```

But when you want to update the exercise array pass an object with isExercises set to true.

```
  chooseThisExercise() {
    this.props.updateValue(numberInTheArrayToChange, newExercise, {isChosenExercises: true});
  }
```